How to create a large index in MySQL 8 on RDS without killing EBSByteBalance%?
I have a table of about 1.3 billion rows that is in active use (millions of new entries every day, around the clock even though there are periods of lower activity). This database is running on a db.t4g.xlarge instance with gp3 storage (1500 IOPS / 500 MB/s throughput).
I need to add a new index to this table, but because it's very large and the index is using three columns this process is several hours long. For the first three hours operations seem undisturbed and free storage space is slowly going down (about 34 GB consumed during this period), then it starts consuming a lot of space very quickly (about 70 GB in 15-20 minutes). This latter spurt causes the EBSByteBalance% to crash down to 0% and the database becoming unreachable.
I assume this is normal behaviour. Maybe first part it's reading a lot from the table, doing some compute and writing to a temporary index/table, and the later part it's committing the data and consolidating it with data that's been received during the write process. But how can I make it not crash from this? Taking a long time to finish the operation is perfectly fine, but I need the database to be usable during this period.

On the last month i have similar case, when i was resolve, creating another table save all operations there, this was populated by task running on spicify time, i have been resolved like this because table master contain millions rows,  and other options was plus memory to my server instance for support this operation

Have you tried using one of the online schema change tools like pt-online-schema-change or gh-ost? If you're using MySQL, one of these is a must have, in my opinion.

is the table partitioned ?, if not it may be worth considering  and migrate the existing to a more optimised structure, that would also facilitate ...
